# Joining a table with an If/Then Statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, attribute-joins

I want to join two tables in ArcMap, but not every feature has the same common attribute in the two tables I want to join. For example, "Feature 1" is in both Table 1 and Table 2 and both tables have the same address for Feature 1, so that would be a good field to base the join on. However, "Feature 2" is in both Table 1 and Table 2, but only Table 1 has the address for Feature 2. Both tables have the same Company name for Feature 2, though, so Company Name would be the ideal field to base the join on.

Is there a way to join two tables with 1 field, if available, if not, then join using a field 2?

Comment: I almost follow the logic and I'm sure it could be done with a script. but I think that the question could use a few more details. Please also take the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: You might try layer definition query to create 2 clones of joined table.

Comment: concatenate the fields together, then join based on that?